# pywin32-cp34 and Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, pip, python-3.4, pywin32

I am running python 3.4.3 and trying to install pywin32-cp34. 
I am typing in the command prompt as such:

```
    C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install pywin32-219-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

I get back:

```
    pywin32-219-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your Python install and module have to be built for the same architecture.  You're trying to install the 64-bit version of pywin32, so make sure your operating system and python are both 64-bit as well.  Otherwise, get the 32-bit version of pywin32.

Comment: Thanks! My python was 32-bit it seems.

Comment: I think there's some obvious potential for confusion in that it's pywin32 no matter if it's 32 or 64 bit, so it would be easy for someone to overlook the 64-bit tag if they hadn't ever been bitten by that before.